# How to turn this JSON into a proper table instead of dot separated columns

Tags: pandas

So I got this JSON

```
{
'A': {
       'total': '$ 28.919', 
       'transacciones': 63, 
       'promedio': '$ 459'
     }, 
'B': {
      'total': '$ 17.169', 
      'transacciones': 27, 
      'promedio': '$ 635'
     }
}
```

And i'm trying to return a table using json_normalize(data) with A/B as columns and total/transacciones/promedio as rows but instead, im getting this:

```
    A.total  A.transacciones A.promedio   B.total  B.transacciones B.promedio
0  $ 28.919               63      $ 459  $ 17.169               27      $ 635
```

What am I doing wrong? I've looked online but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just using the `pd.DataFrame()` constructor:

```
j = {
'A': {
       'total': '$ 28.919', 
       'transacciones': 63, 
       'promedio': '$ 459'
     }, 
'B': {
      'total': '$ 17.169', 
      'transacciones': 27, 
      'promedio': '$ 635'
     }
}

df = pd.DataFrame(j)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                      A         B
total          $ 28.919  $ 17.169
transacciones        63        27
promedio          $ 459     $ 635
```